# Counting items on each row from a table of data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

This is the code I am working with right now

[image]

This is how the sheet called "Category List" looks like

[image]

I have a table of data that is returned by `VLOOKUP`
I would like to run `COUNTA` on each row to get a list of item count

I simply tried running `COUNTA` on the entire data and returned the total item count from the entire table.

Since I pulled this dataset by `VLOOKUP` and used an array of data as a key I thought my attempt to use `COUNTA` on the returned value by the `VLOOKUP` would also return array of item account. However, it didn't.

Comment: Since you are new to here, you should be aware that your screenshots are not particularly useful. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Then edit your question to provide useful data.

Comment: `I would like to run COUNTA on each row to get a list of item count` I am sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to do. Would you please edit your question to explain your data and the result that you want. Would you also provide an example of what a successful outcome looks like.